# Is this javascript code susceptible to DOM based xss

Tags: javascript, dom, xss, referrer

I have a web application that contains code like:

```
If (window.location.href.indexof("test") != -1) {
    window.location.href = document.referrer;
}
```

I can easily trigger this condition if I enter ?test or something in the url, but it just redirect to itself and essentially loops... my question is can I inject xss content by manipulating the javascript document.referrer variable, or can that value be easily changed?

I tried to proxy the request and change the http header but it seems like javascript does not pick up the value from the http header.

Or is this method just flat out bad and should not be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trustworhty user agents will not allow modification of the referer Header unless you explicitly allow them to using the Access-Control-Allow-Headers (don't ever do this basically!). User agents may have some feature to prevent referer Header tampering, but akaik your approach should in fact have altered the `document.referrer` if you did it correctly (this turns out to to be irrelevant however as we can see later on).

The value of `document.referrer` is immune to simple `document.referrer = "my new referrer"` but is however vulnerable to this piece of code `Object.defineProperty(document, "referrer", {get : function(){ return "my new referrer"; }});`.

As such, you must not allow such code to execute on the page in question, otherwise the attacker controls where you are redirected to. Unfortunately this means that this approach can only be used if **every** page where it used, is **fully** protected from XSS attack. Or otherwise your redirect code is **guaranteed** to execute before any XSS injected javascript.

Comment: `Referer` is a _forbidden header name_, [according to the Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name). A compliant browser wouldn't let you set it, regardless of some server's CORS policy.